# Github Actions: run 'git pull' on server when a pull request is done to the master branch

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to create a simple workflow on my dev server, whenever I make a pull request to the master-branch, it should run a git pull on the server, however I cant seem to get it to work with the following:

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: Pull on Push to Master

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the master branch
  push:
    branches: [master]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      # Runs a single command using the runners shell
      - name: Run a one-line script
        run: git pull origin master
```

It basically just says everything is up to date already:

```
Run git pull origin master
From https://github.com/******/******
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
```

Any help appreciated.

Regards

Comment: I assume you are using the default GitHub-hosted runners?

Answer (score 1):

You need setup self host runners on your server and set:

runs-on: self-hosted

instead of

runs-on: ubuntu-latest

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/about-self-hosted-runners